# Take specific things using scrapy (Python )

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I want to take in this werbsit: http://www.americandent.es/productos/
Name,description,image,price,stock and reference of all products.

This is my code:

```
class AmericanSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'American'
start_urls = ['http://www.americandent.es/inicio/log-0']
def parse(self, response):
    return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                formdata={'username': 'name', 'password': 'private'},
                callback=self.after_login)]


# continue scraping with authenticated session...
def after_login(self, response):
# check login succeed before going on
    if "authentication failed" in response.body:
        self.logger.error("Login failed")
        return
# We've successfully authenticated, let's have some fun!
    else:
        print('LOGG!')
        return Request(url='http://www.americandent.es/productos/#!producto',
           callback=self.parse_tastypage)


def parse_tastypage(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    urls = hxs.select('//a/@href').extract()
    for u in urls:
        if urlsplit(u).netloc == urlsplit(response.url).netloc:
            yield Request(url=u, callback=self.parse_tastypage2)
def parse_tastypage2(self, response):
    hxs = scrapy.Selector(response)
    titles = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="list-prd"]/div[3]')
    items = []
    for titles in titles:
        item = StackItem()
        #codigo producto = reference
        reference = titles.select('//*[@id="codigo_producto"]').extract()
        name= titles.select('//*[@id="list-prd"]/div[2]').extract()
        url = titles.select('//*[@id="contProductos"]').extract()
        #tarifa = price
        price = titles.select('//*[@id="lb-tarifas"]/div/div[2]/p/strong').extract()
        stock = titles.select('//*[@id="lb-descripcion"]/p[3]/strong').extract()
        descripton = titles.select('//*[@id="lb-descripcion"]/p[5]').extract()
        imagen=titles.select('//*[@id="stock"]/img').extract()
        item['name']= name
        item['url'] = url
        item['stock']= stock
        item['price']= price
        item['reference']= reference
        item['description']= description
        item['imagen'] = imagen
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

but the result is not as expected:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TryZ8.png)

I need this format columns using csv(| is an example of separator columns):

reference |  price | name  | stock | image

000cab    |  100 € | name1 | 2u    | img1.png

2323ac    |  200 € | name2 | 3u    | img2.png

Comment: It looks not right: `for titles in titles`

Comment: solved but still the same thing happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you are not extracting text, but HTML

e.g : `titles.select('//*[@id="codigo_producto"]').extract()`

this xpath should return Html element that has `id="codigo_producto"`

if you are looking for an immediate child text of  element that has `id="codigo_producto"`

you should use xpath : `//*[@id="codigo_producto"]/text()`

or if you are looking for text of all possible childs of `//*[@id="codigo_producto"]`

you should to use

```
//*[@id="codigo_producto"]//text()
```

try to read some good xpath tutorial